# How to restore the Windows MBR

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bootloader, mbr, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5965 with Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu dual-boot, and I can't restore the Windows 8.1 bootloader with EasyBCD. When I use EasyBCD it always says "Missing Operating System" after I reboot. I tried Windows 8.1 installation media and using bootrec.exe 2 of those commands don't work but /fixmbr does. Can I fix I my MBR with Ubuntu? How do I fix my MBR?

Comment: You can try [/fixmbr](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) within by booting to a WinRE media.

Comment: Whenever I try 2 of the /fixmbr commands (i forgot which ones) it always says undetected file system or something like that then when I reboot, it says "missing operating system".

Comment: You have your answer then.  You cannot repair your the MBR partition.  If you want to update your question to indicate which commands you used exactly there is a small chance somebody might know of another way but without that information that would be tough.

Comment: Well I'll edit it, by the way what's WinPE?

Comment: [Windows PE is the following](https://www.google.com/search?q=WinPE&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)

Comment: It might say Missing Operating System if you don't tick Windows or delete the Windows entry under **Edit Boot Menu**. Does this happen when you choose **Write Existing MBR**?

Comment: You can also restore your Windows MBR by using the **Restore Windows MBR** option in Rescatux. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/728436/windows-7-is-not-loaded-by-the-bios-and-the-computer-is-repeatedly-restarting/728470#728470) for more information about Rescatux.